# How do I get the alias of a function call?

Tags: python, tokenize

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to get the alias of a function call.

what the code works on is for tracking the text:

```
"struct(...)"
```

in the code:

```
x = struct(...)
```

when calling:

```
x()
```

How the IDE works is 'x = struct(...)' only defines an area in a call-tree which creates an indent in the tree, it doesn't actually do anything in the file data.
When you call 'x()' is when the file data is highlighted with the color of 'color = hash("struct(...)")'.

So I need to get the alias 'x' so I can track the call in the code...

I can't exactly help anyone reproduce this as the code for doing so is rather large...
but I just need ideas as I can't seem to find any decent examples on Google.

I'm looking for cases such as:
the obvious:

```
x = struct(...)
```

the not so obvious:

```
p,x,t = 0, struct(...), True
```

the highly irrelevant:

```
p,x,t = (
    0,
    struct(...),
    True )
```

all resulting in a call to x()

I'm using tokenize to get the call-name of struct(), and I have the entire code stored in 'self.codeeditor.data'...

How do I use "struct" to get "x"??

EDIT:
I could mention that x would be in instance of a dynamically created _SUB_STRUCT class returned by struct().

Comment: Do you mean that `x` is an alias for `struct`? Currently, you are assigning the return value of `struct` to `x`; not assigning the function `struct` to `x`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I will fix that up.

Comment: after doing a little research I think I see what you mean... you want me to get the alias of the class returned by struct() right??

Comment: Are you trying to find the names of all variables that are assigned the return value of `struct()`?

Comment: I'm wondering if something more powerful, like `ast`, might not serve your needs better here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `tokenize` will really work here; you'd be better off working on the level of syntax trees using [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and looking for `Assign` nodes.

For example:

```
>>> [n.targets[0].id for n in ast.walk(ast.parse("x = struct()"))
    if isinstance(n, ast.Assign)
        and isinstance(n.value, ast.Call)
        and n.value.func.id == 'struct']
['x']
```

Comment: That looks like it could work, but I'd need to test all of the cases in the question... >_>

Comment: @Tcll true; both your other cases give the same ast though, so you just need to check for `ast.Tuple` as the `n.value` and `ast.Call` within the tuple node.

Comment: Ah ok, the last case was supposed to be a check for "\n".
So from the way it looks, a rework using ast instead of tokenize should get everything running properly for tracking the code.
I think your answer solves this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `dict` to get the functionality you desire:

```
# Relates a label to a function
function_maps = {'a':str, 'b':int, 'c':print}

# Will print 'Hello World!'
function_maps['c']('Hello World!')

# Lets look for the `int` function
for key, value in function_maps.items():
    if value == int:
        print('The alias for `int` is: {}'.format(key))
```

Without seeing more of your code, this is the way I would suggest doing it.

Comment: I suppose mentioning that struct() returns a class called _SUB_STRUCT could help...
so how could I fit _SUB_STRUCT to x??